# Passing Maven properties to Spring Application context files in JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I am trying to get JUnit tests going for a project, but I am having trouble getting properties from the pom injected into the application context xml files.  Specifically, I want to inject the env.code variable which defines which environment the application is running in.

As it stands, the pom contains

```
<properties>
    <env.code>dev</env.code>
    ...
</properties>
```

When the application runs normally, the web.xml file takes the env.code variable and renames it to "environment".  The "environment" variable is used inside the referenced context configuration xml files.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>environment</param-name>
    <param-value>${env.code}</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:SpringBeans.xml classpath:SpringDataSource.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I want to replicate this behavior inside a JUnit test. So far, my simple test case looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/SpringBeans.xml", "/SpringDataSource.xml"})
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void testOne() {}

}
```

Since I am not running the web app, and therefore bypassing the web.xml file, I get an error trying to run the test since there are problems parsing the application context xml files because ${environment} is not being replaced.

How can I go about getting the env.code value defined in the pom injected into the ${environment} placeholder in the application context files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Configure Maven to do resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) on the XML file in question. Then you can use the properties from the POM.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that.  I had to add a property for "environment" for it to work, naturally.  This method doesn't appear to break the app when running normally, which is what I was worried about.